# Asp:BoundField how to force input width

Tags: asp.net, styles, boundfield

Silly question...

Code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PrevDuration" HeaderText="Prev." 
            SortExpression="PrevDuration" ItemStyle-Width="25">
        </asp:BoundField>
```

Html output:

```
<td style="width:25px;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$ctl02" type="text" value="1" size="5" title="Prev."></td>
```

So this code specifies the *td* width, but how instead can I specify the *input* width?

PS. by the way where does that size=5 comes out from?

Comment: any succes? Or do you need a other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `ControlStyle-Width="25px"` property.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PrevDuration" HeaderText="Prev." SortExpression="PrevDuration" ControlStyle-Width="25px">
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a cssclass and set the width in there

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="PrevDuration" 
         HeaderText="Prev." 
         SortExpression="PrevDuration" 
         ItemStyle-Width="25"
         CssClass="inputs"> //note this
      </asp:BoundField>
```

***CSS***

```
.inputs{
   width:...px;
}
```